# Python - Use a list containing keys to make a dictionary out of a string

Tags: python, list, dictionary

With something like this:

```
keys = ["Name:", "Date:", "Time:sec:", "Room"]
string = "Name:BobDate:1/3Time:sec:3:00:00RoomA1"
```

How can I get a dictionary like:

```
dict1 = {"Name" : "Bob", "Date" : "1/3", "Time:sec" : "3:00:00", "Room" : "A1"}
```

Removing the colon is optional.
I am able to remove keys from the string entirely using `re.split()`, `.join()`, and `map()` but I want to create a dictionary instead.

Comment: Where is your string coming from? Is there any way we can get a specific delimiter, such as comma separated? Also, can we make any assumptions about the data, such as that Name will never contain a `:`?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and describe how it doesn't satisfy your requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a regex way...

```
dict(zip(keys, re.match('(.*)'.join(keys + [""]), string).groups()))
```

Demo:

```
>>> if 1:
    import re
    keys = ["Name:", "Date:", "Time:sec:", "Room"]
    string = "Name:BobDate:1/3Time:sec:3:00:00RoomA1"
    dict(zip(keys, re.match('(.*)'.join(keys + [""]), string).groups()))

{'Name:': 'Bob', 'Date:': '1/3', 'Time:sec:': '3:00:00', 'Room': 'A1'}
```

Comment: This looks like the best solution. however when I try it with my actual values, I get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` All the values found in keys are inside the string. Have any idea why it's throwing this error?

Comment: @dv-o Are they all in the string in the correct order?

Comment: They are. Also `string` is of type `str` and `keys` is of type `list` as they should be

Comment: Just went through all the keys to see which one is the dud. I have a key that looks like this: `"Middle name (N/A; or leave blank)?:"`

Comment: @dv-o Ah, ok. Your example's keys only had "ordinary" characters, nothing that's special in regular expressions. If you have such keys, then you'd have to escape them with `re.escape`.

Answer (score 3):

Given your input:

```
keys = ["Name:", "Date:", "Time:sec:", "Room"]
string = "Name:BobDate:1/3Time:sec:3:00:00RoomA1"
```

You can split it using a regular expression preserving the split key itself, eg:

```
split = re.split('({})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in keys)), string)
# ['', 'Name:', 'Bob', 'Date:', '1/3', 'Time:sec:', '3:00:00', 'Room', 'A1']
```

Then, use `dict` with zipping the appropriate slices (we start from 1 because of the leading empty match), eg:

```
dct = dict(zip(split[1::2], split[2::2]))
# {'Date:': '1/3', 'Name:': 'Bob', 'Time:sec:': '3:00:00', 'Room': 'A1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.split()` in a loop works:

```
keys = ["Name:", "Date:", "Time:sec:", "Room"]
s = "Name:BobDate:1/3Time:sec:3:00:00RoomA1"

values = []
temp = s.split(keys[0])[-1]
for key in keys[1:]:
    val, temp = temp.split(key)
    values.append(val)
values.append(temp)

dict1 = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
{'Name:': 'Bob', 'Date:': '1/3', 'Time:sec:': '3:00:00', 'Room': 'A1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line approach,

```
In [40]: dict(zip(keys,[string.split(j)[-1].split(keys[-1])[0] if i == (len(keys) - 1) else string.split(j)[-1].split(keys[i+1])[0] for i,j in enumerate(keys)]))
Out[40]: {'Date:': '1/3', 'Name:': 'Bob', 'Room': 'A1', 'Time:sec:': '3:00:00'}
```

I know it's pretty complex approach :), Just to show the different option of answer.

Answer (score 0):

We could replace the keys in string with a rowbreak (something to split by). And then perform a dict(zip(...

```
keys = ["Name:", "Date:", "Time:sec:", "Room"]
string = "Name:BobDate:1/3Time:sec:3:00:00RoomA1"

for key in keys:
    string = string.replace(key,"\n")

d = dict(zip(keys,string.split('\n')[1:])) # 1: to handle first row break
```

d equals:

```
{'Date:': '1/3', 'Name:': 'Bob', 'Room': 'A1', 'Time:sec:': '3:00:00'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
keys = ["Name:", "Date:", "Time:sec:", "Room"]
string = "Name:BobDate:1/3Time:sec:3:00:00RoomA1"
new_data = dict(zip(map(lambda x:x[:-1], keys), filter(None, re.split('\*', re.sub('|'.join(keys), '*', string)))))
```

Output:

```
{'Date': '1/3', 'Time:sec': '3:00:00', 'Name': 'Bob', 'Roo': 'A1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my journey on finding the answer

```
In [17]: import re

In [18]: keys = ["Name:", "Date:", "Time:sec:", "Room"]

In [19]: string = "Name:BobDate:1/3Time:sec:3:00:00RoomA1"

In [20]: separators = '|'.join(keys)

In [21]: separators
Out[21]: 'Name:|Date:|Time:sec:|Room'

In [22]: re.split(separators, string)
Out[22]: ['', 'Bob', '1/3', '3:00:00', 'A1']

In [23]: re.split(separators, string)[1:]
Out[23]: ['Bob', '1/3', '3:00:00', 'A1']

In [24]: values = re.split(separators, string)[1:]

In [25]: dict(zip(keys, values))
Out[25]: {'Date:': '1/3', 'Name:': 'Bob', 'Room': 'A1', 'Time:sec:': '3:00:00'}

In [26]: dict1 = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

## Notes

- Line 20, 21: Create a list of separators to use in `re.split` later on. The pipe symbol (`|`) means "**or**" in regular expression
- Line 22: Split the string using this list of separators. We almost got what we want except for the first element that is blank
- Line 23 fixes that first blank element
- Line 24, with that, we assign the result to values, to be used later to construct the dictionary
- Line 25, 26: Construct that dictionary and assign to `dict1`